# How to distinguish the same text in single UILAbel when I click by ActiveLabel - Swift3?

Tags: ios, swift, string, uilabel

I have a string text like this:

> @Tim @Tim Hello.

And How to distinguish two of @Tim is different person? 
 
like tags? or any function?

I have a data array like this:

> [ ["Tim": "AppName://app/user/aa3b77411825b88b318d77gg"], ["Tim": "AppName://app/user/aa3b77411825b88b318d77tt"] ]

When I click first @Tim get "AppName://app/user/aa3b77411825b88b318d77gg".

Then I click second @Tim get "AppName://app/user/aa3b77411825b88b318d77tt".

```
textLabel.customize { (label) in

    label.text = string

    label.handleMentionTap({ (mentionString) in

         print(mentionString)
         //How to distinguish two of @Tim?
    })

}
```

Now I can click the label,but metionString always print Tim.
I don't know which Tim is clicked.
Have any idea to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: You can't with this library. Because the closure gives only a String, it doesn't give too the link (that can differentiate them). I'm doing this from memory talking about this lib on another question on SO, but it would be nice to give a link to its github.

Comment: Also, it would be really much simpler to use a `UITextView`. Small modification would make it appears for the user as a `UILabel` and it manages click on "links".

Comment: Check the labels with if labels. If you e.g. hold a reference to your first Tim label as `tim1Label`, in the closure you can compare `if label === tim1Label`.

Comment: @Lukas Sorry, have any simple to let me know?